# Vite server crashing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vite

I am working on laravel and vue auth ui with vite when i run the server it is crashing and giving this message

node:internal/errors:490

```
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

^
```

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/testlvel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Configuration/Value/IniSettingCollectionIterator.php'

I have searched everywhere but i haven't got solution please anyone help?

Comment: You can increase the maximum number of file watchers on your system
'echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p'